# 100 errors with digitalPinMap[] using VS code and platformio in Sd2PinMap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, platformio

I just started a new Platformio project in VS Code and included SD library.
On build 100 errors appeared and I really don't know how to fix them as googling them didn't bring any fruit.
I'm using Arduino Uno Rev 2 WiFi
**Atmega328P**

`a value of type "DDRDClass *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "volatile uint8_t *"`
and
`'DDRD' was not declared in this scope` are some of the errors involved.

this is my `main.cpp` file if it can help

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
  }
  Serial.print('Initializing SD card...');
  if (!SD.begin(4))
  {
    Serial.println('initialization failed!');
    while (1)
      ;
  }
  Serial.println('initialization done');
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Here is the code that returns the errors

```
#else  // defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
// 168 and 328 Arduinos

// Two Wire (aka I2C) ports
uint8_t const SDA_PIN = 18;
uint8_t const SCL_PIN = 19;

// SPI port
uint8_t const SS_PIN = 10;
uint8_t const MOSI_PIN = 11;
uint8_t const MISO_PIN = 12;
uint8_t const SCK_PIN = 13;

static const pin_map_t digitalPinMap[] = {
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 0},  // D0  0
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 1},  // D1  1
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 2},  // D2  2
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 3},  // D3  3
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 4},  // D4  4
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 5},  // D5  5
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 6},  // D6  6
  {&DDRD, &PIND, &PORTD, 7},  // D7  7
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 0},  // B0  8
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 1},  // B1  9
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 2},  // B2 10
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 3},  // B3 11
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 4},  // B4 12
  {&DDRB, &PINB, &PORTB, 5},  // B5 13
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 0},  // C0 14
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 1},  // C1 15
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 2},  // C2 16
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 3},  // C3 17
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 4},  // C4 18
  {&DDRC, &PINC, &PORTC, 5}   // C5 19
};
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, pick one. I guess `Serial.begin(9600);` this is C++, so you should drop the C tag. Please don't use an image for the error message -- [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also your error messages are for lines 300+ of Sd2PinMap.h the contents of which we can only guess at...

Comment: General advice: find the first error message, focus on fixing that, the rest is usually just confused noise. If the faulting code is not yours and it is expected to work, ignore the code and focus on your project setup (are you following some instructions? revisit those).

Comment: `Serial.println('initialization done');` These are the wrong quotation marks for `c` or `c++`

Comment: The readme for the SD library says to use the SdFat library instead: [https://github.com/adafruit/SD/blob/master/README.txt](https://github.com/adafruit/SD/blob/master/README.txt)

Comment: Did you try to do the same in Arduino IDE? And did it work?

Comment: @NeWi-SL I did try it but there it refuses to upload my program because it cannot find tho correct port (only COM1 is visible)

Comment: @ILKOGAMER Did it appear in Device Manager? And which line and file is giving you the above error?

Comment: If you can please upload a screenshot of the error output. Thanks

Comment: I tried to compile your code in a different board  in platformio and it compile without any errors